# How to define TransferConfig for BigQuery Data Transfer Service

Tags: google-bigquery

The source projectId and source datasetId are supposed to be defined in the Params. But I am not sure how to set Params properly.

```
      TransferConfig transferConfig = TransferConfig.newBuilder()
                                          .setDisplayName(jobName)
                                          .setDestinationDatasetId(dstDatasetId)
                                          .setParams(Struct.newBuilder().build())
                                          .build();
```

The corresponding cli looks like this.

```
bq mk --transfer_config 
--data_source="cross_region_copy" 
--display_name=copy-cli-display-name
--project_id=play 
--target_dataset=copy_dataset_cli 
--params='{"source_project_id": "tough-talent", "source_dataset_id": "billing"}'
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually Google [BigQuery Data Transfer](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/transfer) service represents a plenty of client libraries with a flexible way developing data transport capabilities across BigQuery [Data Transfer API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest).

Assuming that your aim is just to develop transfer service via compatible Bigquery transfer [Java client](https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigquerydatatransfer) library, you might be looking for [*TransferConfig.Builder*](https://googleapis.github.io/googleapis/java/all/latest/apidocs/com/google/cloud/bigquery/datatransfer/v1/TransferConfig.Builder.html#setParams-com.google.protobuf.Struct.Builder-) class in order to create data transfer configuration. This class contains dedicated methods for declaring destination Bigquery location path, however source data transfer settings are basically enclosed in **setParams()** method, invoking [*Struct()*](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/Struct.html?is-external=true) class for propagating key-value structured data parameters, originally included in **google.protobuf** [package](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.Value).

Due to the fact that:

> `Struct` represents a structured data value, consisting of fields 
>   which map to dynamically typed values.

You can supposedly use either [*putAllFields()*](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/Struct.Builder.html#putAllFields-java.util.Map-) or [*putFields()*](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/Struct.Builder.html#putFields-java.lang.String-com.google.protobuf.Value-) methods for mapping key-value parameters within `Struct.newBuilder()` class as demonstrated  in this example:

```
Struct struct1 = Struct.newBuilder().putFields(
        "some-key", Value.newBuilder().setStringValue("some-value").build()
    ).build();
```

Find more related examples [here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=com.google.protobuf.Struct).